# Can't open this message

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc, mime, ndef

I'm writing an WP8 NFC Application.

I send (ndef) messages from my computer to the phone.
On the phone I subscribed for NDEF Messages: `_proximityDevice.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF", MessageReceivedHandler);`

When I receive a message, my `MessageReceiveHandler` get's called, and I can process the message.

```
private async void MessageReceivedHandler(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
{
    var rawMsg = message.Data.ToArray();
    var ndefMsg = NdefMessage.FromByteArray(rawMsg);
    var ndefRec = ndefMsg[0];

    string recordType = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ndefRec.Type, 0, ndefRec.Type.Length);

    Debug.WriteLine(recordType);
}
```

This works fine. But at the same time WP8 shows a message box:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| Can't open                                  |
|                                             |
| Sorry, your phone can't recognise this type |
| of file.                                    |
|                                             |
| [close]                                     |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Do I have to tell WP8 somewhere that the app accepts the message? Or why is that message appearing?

Btw, I'm using a custom MIME Type `application/ch.cimnine.myapp.v1`. Do I have to register this MIME-Type somehow with WP8?

Comment: Unfortunately, this behavior of the Windows Phone 8 OS can’t be changed,you have no control over phone’s NFC prompts

Answer (score 0):

When you subscribe on NDEF protocole, you will receive all NDEF messages but OS can prompt.

Unfortunately [Mimetype are prompted by WP8](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Use_NFC_tags_with_Windows_Phone_8#WindowsMime..28mimetype.29)

To avoid the prompt message you can use [Windows. protocol](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Use_NFC_tags_with_Windows_Phone_8#Windows..3Csubtype.3E) or other low level NDEF message.